# Group and reduce list based on column values

Tags: r

I would like to group and reduce list based on column values.

Here is very simple example. The solution should be preferably in base R and should not include direct referencing to the letters in column `name` as I have more `variables` there.

```
l <- list(data.frame(name=c("X"),price=1), data.frame(name=c("X"),price=1.2), data.frame(name=c("X"),price=2.2), data.frame(name=c("Y"),price=2.5))
```

Desired output:

```
[[1]]
    name price
 1    X     1
 2    X   1.2
 3    X   2.2
[[2]]
    name price
1    Y   2.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `rbind` the `list` elements and then `split` the output `data.frame` by 'name' column

```
 d1 <- do.call(rbind, l)
 split(d1, d1$name)
```

Comment: oh, I reduced my actual problem so that now it doesn't represent what I actually need. However this is correct solution to the question provided. I will post new one :) Thanks

Comment: @Maximilian You can update the post with a new example/expected output if this is related

Comment: yes, I would, but I have to figure it out first and can do so first later today.

Comment: @Maximilian I am still trying to figure out what exactly the actual problem is.  This solution doesn't rely on the letters in the 'name' column.

Comment: sure, your solution is as required by the example provided. I have got just multiple entries in each of the list and that consists list of lists. I will post new question later on. Thanks.